# How to wake up waiting SwingWorker?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a `SwingWorker` that is running in the background.  After it works on
some stuff.   It will wait.  When the user push a button, the `MyListener` will
be invoked and wake up the worker to continue do some stuff.  It is not working
like I thought it would.   It throws an exception at the bottom.  Please tell
me what I did wrong.

```
 MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();    

 class MyListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

         //DO some stuff and wake up worker  
         worker.notify ();           
    }
}

class MyWorker extends SwingWorker {

    boolean _work = true;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println ("in myWorker");
        while (_work == true) {

          //DO some stuff here
            wait();        
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at worker.Worker$2.actionPerformed(Worker.java:54)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a synchronized block around the `notify` call.

```
synchronized (worker) {
    worker.notify();
}
```

Now, having said that, you are generally discouraged from using instance variables as monitor locks and instead use a `static final` lock object as (amongst other things) it decreases the potential of having the wrong instance

Comment: Thank you.  That synchronized did fix the exception.   For some reason, the worker still does not wake up.   Am I still missing something ?

Comment: Do the same thing in the worker (except call wait), I bet the work has already thrown the same exception, but you've not seen it yet because of the way the worker works

Comment: That makes a change, let my wife know ;)